# Html style:font-family gets messed up while rendering

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, font-family

I'm trying to create a stick-note kind of program using JqueryUI. I've created the note with different fonts like this.

```html
<div class="object ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable selected" id="element_9" style="top: 320.919px; left: 1145.88px; color: rgb(185, 54, 68); font-size: 1008.51%; width: 571px; right: auto; height: 606px; bottom: auto; transform: none; font-weight: 400; font-family: &quot;Allerta Stencil&quot;, sans-serif;"
  data-type="text" data-font="f65">
  <div class="text-editable" contenteditable="false" style="cursor: all-scroll;">Enter your text here </div>
  <div class="ui-rotatable-handle ui-draggable" style="transform: scale(2.22222);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(2.22222);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(2.22222);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(2.22222);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(2.22222);"></div>
</div>
```

Now I'm saving them using PHP as a HTML file. And trying to load the HTML file back, this is what I'm receiving after the browser renders the HTML file.

```html
<div class="object ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable selected" id="element_8" style="top: 320.919px; left: 1145.88px; color: rgb(185, 54, 68); font-size: 1008.51%; width: 571px; right: auto; height: 606px; bottom: auto; transform: none; font-weight: 400; z-index: auto;"
  allerta="" stencil ",=" " sans-serif;"="" data-type="text" data-font="f65">
  <div class="text-editable" contenteditable="false" style="cursor: all-scroll;">Enter your text here </div>
  <div class="ui-rotatable-handle ui-draggable" style="transform: scale(5.71429);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(5.71429);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(5.71429);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(5.71429);"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90; transform: scale(5.71429);"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see the styles of the parent tag is not consistent. I've copy pasted the above outerHTML from Chrome Inspector. I can see Chrome automatically inserts a "" between the font family when I do this

```
object.css({"font-family": this.font_family});
```

and *this.font-family* is from a JSON that looks like this

```
var fonts = [{font_family : 'Allerta Stencil, sans-serif', name: 'f65', val: "Allerta Stencil"},...]
```

Then why is it when the file is reloaded, the style is not read back properly? Is there a way I could overcome this. I've read some SO questions similar to this where font name with spaces need quotes. My question is if quotes are included by the browser, then why is it when reloading the HTML file quotes are ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using double quotes to wrap the value of the of the `style` attribute, you will need to use single quotes within that, to wrap font names.

At the moment, you are using the following:

```
style="font-family:&quot;Alerta Stencil&quot;,sans-serif;"
```

But `&quot;` is the entity for a double quotation mark so, essentially, what you've written is:

```
style="font-family:"Alerta Stencil",sans-serif;"
```

The second quotation mark above is "closing" the `style` attribute immediately after `font-family:` (I'm guessing that somewhere along the way your PHP is parsing the `&quot;` entity and outputting `"`).

The solution, therefore, is to change your `style` attribute to the following:

```
style="font-family:'Alerta Stencil',sans-serif;"
```

To achieve this, you will need to change the JSON to the following:

```
var fonts=[{font_family:"'Allerta Stencil',sans-serif",name:"f65",val:"Allerta Stencil"};
```

Comment: Actually I mentioned jquery inserted the quotes while doing $(object).css('font-family','...');

Comment: I made the same changes myself. But this is what chrome gives after applying the change

style="top: 749.575px; left: 1651.03px; color: rgb(185, 54, 68); width: 571px; right: auto; height: 154px; bottom: auto; transform: none; font-weight: 400; font-size: 1008.51%; font-family: "Allerta Stencil", sans-serif;"

PHP saved that as
style="top: 812.433px; left: 542.454px; color: rgb(185, 54, 68); right: auto; bottom: auto; transform: none; font-size: 1680.8%; height: auto; width: 751.857px; font-weight: 400; font-family: &quot;Allerta Stencil&quot;, sans-serif;"

Comment: But when loading it back it messes up the HTML

Comment: Sorry about this. But in the back-end while reading back the html I had used html_entity_decode. But using solution and some custom code helped in reverting the deformed style. Thank you @Shaggy